# Xamarin Android: add custom files to apk during build

Tags: android, filesystems, xamarin, xamarin.android, monodevelop

i need to add some files to be accessed by deployed android application for test purposes (they will be downloaded from internets later). particularly, i need files in cache directory for application to see them

is there any way to add them there at build time?

or any time at all. i can't even add them to apk\cache with android debug monitor! (it says Failed to push the items)

is it really the only way to do it is download them from internet i wonder.. o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Assets folder

Any raw assets you want to be deployed with your application can be placed in
this directory (and child directories) and given a Build Action of "AndroidAsset".

These files will be deployed with you package and will be accessible using Android's `AssetManager`, like this:

```
public class ReadAsset : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        InputStream input = Assets.Open ("my_asset.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: i was thinking about it, but looks like it will not bring the files to cache older. from other hand, i just don't know why i didn't even think to move it at runtime myself lol